# google map marker icon not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to implement a google map where the user will be able to find search for a place of its choice. The map is showing up just fine and the search box is also working. The only problem is that the map marker is not showing up. I have the following script. It seems that the icon var is never used but i dont know why. Can anyone help me?

```
<script>


    function initAutocomplete() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: { lat: 55.86515, lng: -4.25763 },
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });


        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);


        map.addListener('bounds_changed', function () {
            searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
        });

        var markers = [];

        searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function () {
            var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

            if (places.length == 0) {
                return;
            }


            markers.forEach(function (marker) {
                marker.setMap(null);
            });
            markers = [];


            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            places.forEach(function (place) {
                if (!place.geometry) {
                    console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
                    return;
                }
                var icon = {
                    url: place.icon,
                    size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                    anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
                };

                markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    icon: "~/flag.jpg",
                    title: place.name,
                    position: place.geometry.location,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
                }));

                if (place.geometry.viewport) {

                    bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
                } else {
                    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
                }
            });
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: The icon `"~/flag.jpg"` isn't available.  Use a fully qualified URL.  You can verify that the code is working by commenting out that line (`icon: "~/flag.jpg",`) ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/6f3xbe85/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path of image which you have given may not working.So, try the following to verifiy. **Which worked for me**.

```
var markerImage = 'http://www.mapsmarker.com/wp-content/uploads/leaflet-maps-marker-icons/bar_coktail.png';

markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                icon: markerImage,
                title: place.name,
                position: place.geometry.location,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
            }));
```

Can try [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shusilsatyal/9Lyc0zw3/5/)

Comment: How is that supposed to **answer** the question? OP is trying to use a local file as the icon. Not from a public URL. The above code shows `http://` and your fiddle uses `https://` why is that? And how could you make sure the public URL could be loaded with the right protocol?

Comment: @MrUpsidown Great !

Comment: @PashupatiKhanal I am not going to edit an answer on a question that should be/is closed, as it shouldn't be answered in the first place. The question isn't clear / cannot be reproduced = close = no answer. And again this doesn't answer the question, proposes a solution that is not what OP seems to be trying to achieve. I don't even see why OP accepted it... You should get more familiar with this community before telling others how to behave.